# Is it possible to define a function with callable parameter, where callable has unspecified number of arguments?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Let's say I have trait like this:

```rust
trait Task<T> {
  fn solve(&self, func: fn(T) -> T) -> T;
}
```

That setup allows to pass function only like:

```rust
fn solution(n: i32) -> i32{n}
```

But i want to pass functions with any number of arguments like:

```rust
fn solution_2(n: String, i: i32) -> i32{0}
fn solution_3() -> i32 {0}
// etc
```

I don't understand how to define(and can i define) `func` parameter in `.solve()` method so it can accept callable with any number of parameters.

I assume it's impossible because then there is no way to knowing how to call `func` inside solve.

So it seems that it's wrong way to think.

Comment: What do you want to do with this function?

Comment: Also, does the trait need to be object safe?

Comment: As for this example, i made workaround which is more logical and without a need to pass callable to method. So my question here simply about possibility to define callabl e with not determined number of arguments.  I am new to rust so question about object safety not clear to me, so apparently asnwer is no.

Comment: Rust doesn't have anything to generalize over the number of arguments of a function. Use tuples.

Comment: "Object safety" means being able to create `dyn Task`.